# Left join Query with eloquent

Tags: join, laravel, laravel-4

I have two classes: Degree and College,

```
class Degree extends Eloquent {
      public function title(){
         return $this->degree_title;
      }
      public function college(){
         return $this->belongsTo('College','college_code');
      }
}
class College extends Eloquent {
      public function title(){
         return $this->college_title;
      }
}
```

I have it set as belongsTo because it breaks on hasOne(), the error is:

```
Call to a member function getResults() on a non-object
```

If that is in the right direction i'm not sure.

What I've been trying is this searching for the degree using a slug(it makes for better analytics), then pass the results to a blade I have created.

Note: There is a Degrees table and a Colleges table, I can run queries without joins:

Controller for Degree:

```
class DegreeController extends BaseController {
    public function single($slug)
       {
            $degree = Degree::where('slug', '=', $slug)->get();
            return View::make('degrees.single', array('degree' => $degree));
       }
}
```

The Single view:

```
@extends('master')
{{ -- Single Degree Blade-- }}
@section('content')

@foreach($major as $m)
    <div>
        <h1>{{ $m->title() }}</p>
        <p>{{ $m->college->title() }}</p>
        <p>Holland: {{ $m->holland() }}</p>
    </div>
@endforeach

@stop
```

What i'm noticing is that using `$m->college->title()` results in the error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'colleges.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `colleges` where `colleges`.`id` = ? limit 1) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 'UAGSC', ))

Which is indicating that it's ignoring my custom key, which isn't id and isn't an integer, it's a specific 5 letter varchar.

Can anyone give me any suggestions on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the primary key(ID) of the College table to the same value that college_code is referencing. The ID isn't auto increment or an integer, I'm making use of an already unique identifier which makes it easier in the long run for me.

Answer (score 0):

When joining, make use of the primary key. Mostly ID.

Make the Primary key an INT and AUTO INCREMENT.

You will succeed.